# On the solutions of $y''(t)=f(y(t))$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This topic has been inspired by some time spending on trying to refining my knowledge about PDE's in general. Then everybody knows how to solve $$y''(t)=\pm y(t).$$ Then I tried to slightly modify the question and I focused on $$(\therefore)\;y''(t)=f(y(t)),\; f\in C^1(\mathbb R,\mathbb R).$$ What I was trying to do was to derive some general properties about the solutions to this equation. In particular I ask to you, since I was not able to answer myself:

Must a solution of $(\therefore)$, not identically zero, have necessarily a finite number of zeroes on $[0,1]$? My idea was to derive an estimate like

$$|y(\eta)-y(\xi)|\leq C|\eta-\xi|^p,\; p>1;$$ Moreover, if a solution $y$ were to have an infinite number of zeroes in $[0,1]$, the the set of zeroes should have an accumulation point, and in this point all the derivatives should be equal to $0$ by continuity, then maybe the function should remain to much squeezed to be different from zero.

Hope you can help me because this interests me a lot.

Many thanks for your attention.

(I tried to post this on mathlinks as well but nobody answered me yet)

Comment: Try an analysis in the phase plane: the equation $$\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx}p^2 = \frac{d}{dx} F(y(x))$$ where $p=y'$ and $F'=f$.

Comment: Sorry, the word "is" was in my brain but not in my fingers! The equation IS...

Comment: What do you mean by a finite number of zeros? Do you mean that the set $\{ t | y(t) = 0 \}$ is finite? The equation $y'' = -y$, $y(0) = 0, y'(0)=1$ has a solution $y(t) = \sin t$ which has an infinite number of zeros.

Comment: Yes.. in $[0, 1]$.. not on the whole real line..

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a familiar type of ODE. In the following I shall deal with the "purely formal" aspect of it. Questions of sign under the square root or behavior near special points have to be treated "at runtime".

Let $F$ be a primitive of the given function $y\mapsto f(y)$. Multiplying the given differential equation by $y'(t)$ we get
$$y''(t)y'(t)=f\bigl(y(t)\bigr)\,y'(t)$$
or
$${d\over dt}\left({1\over2} y'^2(t)-F\bigl(y(t)\bigr)\right)=0\ .$$
Therefore there is a constant $C$ such that
$$y'(t)=\sqrt{2F\bigl(y(t)\bigr)+C}\ .$$
Now the variables can be separated:
$${dy\over\sqrt{2F(y)+C}}= dt\ .$$
This shows that ODEs of the considered type can be solved by quadratures. (The trick of multiplying by $y'$ is absolutely standard in mechanics, where it leads to the principle of "conservation of energy".)

Comment: But how to conclude on the finiteness of the zeroes?

Comment: An analysis of the curves $p^2 = 2F(y)+C$ in the $(y,p)$-space might help. What happens when $y=0$? Is $p \neq 0$? And if $p=0$, does it change sign nearby?

Comment: How does this answer address the zeros?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do what Christian did.

The equation does not explicitly mention $t$ (only $y(t)$), so we can reduce to a first-order equation.  Say $u = y'$ and get an equation for $u$ as a function of $y$ like this:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dt} &= \frac{du}{dy}\cdot\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{du}{dy}\cdot u
\\
\text{so}\qquad y'' &= f(y)\qquad\text{becomes}
\\
u \frac{du}{dy} &= f(y)
\end{align}$$
a separable first order linear equation.  Solve it.  Once you get $u$ as a function of $y$, you have an integration problem to get (implicitly) $y$ as a function of $t$.

Comment: Still i cannot see how this implies the finiteness of the number of zeroes..

Answer (score 1):

As you said, if the set of zeroes has an accumulation point $x$, then the solution and its derivatives should vanish there. In particular, this implies that $f(0)=f(y(x))=y''(x)=0$. Then by ODE uniqueness theory the solution must vanish everywhere, because $y\equiv0$ is a solution.

A detailed treatment of such equations can be found in Cazenave's notes *An introduction to semilinear elliptic equations*. Google can find it easily for you.

Comment: I don't see how uniqueness follows.. I mean I cannot apply the standard theorems.. can you detail your argument? Thanks..

Comment: Why must the derivative vanish at an accumulation point?

Comment: @uforoboa: You can replace the equation by an equivalent first order system, then you can apply standard theory.

Comment: @copper.hat: It is not? I am not sure. Let us think.

Comment: Can you show me how? If you're right I will accept your answer because is what I am looking for.. @copper.. continuity and mean value theorems do the job..

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to use the fact that $t \in [0,1]$. The solution to $y'' = -y$ has an infinite number of zeros over $\mathbb{R}$. You need something else to conclude that the derivative vanishes.

Comment: Indeed.. but if the zeroes were infinitely many in $[0, 1]$, they will have an accumulation in this set..

Comment: I realize that $[0,1]$ is compact, however the proof hinges on showing that $y'$ is zero at an accumulation point. I believe it does, but it needs to be proved.

Comment: @uforoboa:  The equation is equivalent to $(y',z')=G(y,z):=(z,f(y))$. Obviously $G$ is $C^1$ so standard theory applies.